# JPA entity with bill of material concept showing error when eclipse IDE changed from juno to helios

Tags: eclipse, orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, eclipse-juno

I am facing a unique issue while implementing the bill of material concept .
**Jar used**: eclipselink 2.4.0 , javax.persistence

The entity is as follows:

```java
            @Id
            @TableGenerator(name = "Config_Key_Incrementor", table = "id_generator", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_value", pkColumnValue = "conifg_id_gen", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = TABLE, generator = "Config_Key_Incrementor")
            @Column(name = "config_id")
            private int configId;

            @Column(name = "config_name")
            private String configName;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to Bill_Of_Material
            @ManyToOne
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="config_id")
            private Configuration parent;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to Bill_Of_Material
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
            private List<Configuration> children = new ArrayList<Configuration>();

            public Configuration getParent() {
                return parent;
            }

            public void setParent(Configuration parent) {
                this.parent = parent;
            }

            public List<Configuration> getChildren() {
                return children;
            }

            public void setChildren(List<Configuration> children) {
                this.children = children;
            }

            public int getConfigId() {
                return configId;
            }

            public void setConfigId(int configId) {
                this.configId = configId;
            }

            public String getConfigName() {
                return configName;
            }

            public void setConfigName(String configName) {
                this.configName = configName;
            }
```

The above code works fine when the IDE environment is eclipse juno.

**Output** (IDE is eclipse juno)-

```
CREATE TABLE configuration
(
config_id integer NOT NULL,
config_name character varying(255),
parent_config_id integer,
CONSTRAINT configuration_pkey PRIMARY KEY (config_id ),
CONSTRAINT fk_configuration_parent_config_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_config_id)
    REFERENCES configuration (config_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

But when the same code is not giving error when the IDE is eclipse helios.

**Output** here(IDE is eclipse helios) is:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration    
(    
config_id integer NOT NULL,  
config_name character varying(255),    
CONSTRAINT configuration_pkey PRIMARY KEY (config_id ),  
CONSTRAINT fk_configuration_config_id FOREIGN KEY (config_id)  
       REFERENCES configuration (config_id) MATCH SIMPLE  
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION  
)
```

The above code works with a small modification(as suggested in on of the posts- [JPA entity giving error on implementing Bill of material concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923021/jpa-entity-giving-error-on-implementing-bill-of-material-concept))

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_config_id", referencedColumnName="config_id")
private Configuration parent;
```

**Problem:** I am not able to figure out why this behaviour is shown with just IDE version change

Comment: What is generated for the table creation when using Juno?

Comment: @Chris i just updated the question with output from juno environment too.                                                                     Output(IDE eclipse juno):

    CREATE TABLE configuration
    (
    config_id integer NOT NULL,
    config_name character varying(255),
    parent_config_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT configuration_pkey PRIMARY KEY (config_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_configuration_parent_config_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_config_id)
        REFERENCES configuration (config_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )

Comment: The code is not the same in both IDEs as the table created from Juno is correctly using a foreign key field.  I dont know how much time you want to put into breaking the project you know is wrong, but try refreshing, a clean and rebuild in Juno.

Comment: you may need to drop the table as it could have been created using the proper joincolumn, and cannot get recreated with the pkjoincolumn change.  So e code might still be wrong as it might not be populations the fk field, just you aren't getting an exception at persist.  Check what is given back isn't referencing itself after an em.refresh.